# Why does the UA's link color beat an author's color for (say) body?

Tags: css

I'm looking for the portion of the CSS standard that explains this (rather sensible) behavior. That is, if I write the property `body { color: green; }` I'd expect (reading the documentation, not from experience) all of `body`'s children to have green color, including (visited and not visited) `a`s. I'm aware there are user agent definitions, but the [order of the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order), in ascending order of preference, is:

1. user agent declarations
2. user normal declarations
3. author normal declarations
4. author important declarations
5. user important declarations

Why, then, isn't the inherited value of `color` used for links? I realize this would greatly limit the usefulness of the user agent's default style sheets, but I'm just curious about why this isn't a violation of the standard. I'm clearly missing something!

**Edit:** My "why" refers strictly to explicit support in the CSS standard, not to why it would make sense.

Comment: The link colours are defined in the UA css however they are defined specifically for the anchors which will override the inherit value from body

Comment: Thanks, Huangism. Yes, I know from practice it works like that, but based on what I can read it shouldn't... It looks like the standard should have a note on the interplay between the cascade and inheritance.

Comment: There is a note somewhere, there was another question asked about similar things and someone had linked an explanation but I forgot what the question was called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a second order to the cascade and that's the order of which selectors override which other selectors.

For example, if you define in **your** stylesheet:

```
body { color: green; }
h1 { color: purple; }
```

the `h1` has higher order of importance and will OVERRIDE the greenness of the `body`.

As to the general order of the cascade, this is the correct order, but you have to realize that user agent declarations vs. the things you define in a stylesheet are overridden SEPERATELY FOR EACH ELEMENT.

For example, let's say that the user agent has defined:

```
body { font-size: 10px; }
h1 { font-size: 20px; }
a { color: purple; }
```

and you are defining in your stylesheet:

```
body { font-size: 30px; color: green; }
```

Everything in the `body` will be 30px green except for those other two tags that the user agent stylesheet has already defined. You have to override ALL of them. Not just one user agent definition must be overridden but ALL OF THEM have to be overridden. Your styles WILL take precedence over the user agent stylesheet. Just gotta be careful to catch them all.

This is officially termed "inheritance". You're right, I guess the writers of w3 didn't specify explicitly how only one element at a time from the UA stylesheet gets overridden by your own personal stylesheet. They maybe thought it was obvious but they should probably add into the official documentation how the two should "mesh together", here, in this official documentation of inheritance: [w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html](http://w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html)

They did mention it in the wiki, I think we've discussed, so I'll include it in the answer, as well: [w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade](http://w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade)

Comment: Thanks for your input. OK, I know it works like this, but I'm mainly looking for the legalese... where is this stated in the standard? Clearly `h1` being explicitly purple should without further explanation "block" the green color it would otherwise inherit from `body` (and pass on purple to its descendants). And I know in practice your example works the way it does... but again, reading the standard I feel your defining `font-size: 30px` as an author should be applied wherever there is inheritance, and override all the affected UA properties...

Comment: @ezequiel-garzon in "legalese" this is officially termed "inheritance". From http://www.w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade : Elements in the HTML markup inherit properties from their parent (containing) elements and pass them on to their children. But if a child element has a style already explicitly defined for it, of course this explicit definition will override the inheritance. This is basically the official term for what I had already explained in the answer. The user agent stylesheet has explicitly defined a style for `<a>` which is a child of `<body>`.

Comment: That's closer, though still a wiki! I can't believe this issue is not addressed in the standard proper.

Comment: @ezequiel-garzon This IS addressed in the standard proper, I just gave the link to w3's wiki because I thought it might be easier to read/understand.  Here is that "legalese" link you wanted specifically, I'm sorry~~ http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html Child elements only inherit the styles of parent elements if the child doesn't already have a style defined for it. Basically, `<a>` will NOT inherit `<body>`'s style because `<a>` already has a style defined for it. (in the user agent stylesheet)

Comment: I'm upvoting all your constructive remarks, and for hearing me out :) No, the wiki (by the official W3C) does address the potential conflict. The cascade by itself in the standard ignores the issue. Now, at the risk of driving you mad, I can see how it works in practice, but it's far from obvious. The standard is greatly careful about specificity, order and other aspects, while this is officially neglected. If you edit your answer and include the (official) wiki I'll mark it as correct, but to me it's a shame that passage is not normative.

Comment: Reading the wiki carefully, I can't really see it addresses the issue either. Truth be told, I haven't read the standard from cover to cover! It must be covered somewhere...

Comment: I guess [the inheritance definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#inheritance) explains it, a bit in passing for my taste: """**If no color has been assigned** to the EM element, the emphasized "is" will inherit the color of the parent element."""

Answer (score 1):

This is the cascade order ([taken from w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html))

To find the value for an element/property combination, user agents must apply the following sorting order:

1. Find all declarations that apply to the element and property in question, for the target media type.
2. Sort according to importance (normal or important) and origin (author, user, or user agent). In ascending order of precedence:

   - user agent declarations
   - user normal declarations
   - author normal declarations
   - author important declarations
   - user important declarations
3. Sort rules with the same importance and origin by specificity of selector: **more specific selectors will override more general ones**. Pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes are counted as normal elements and classes, respectively.
4. Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins. Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself.
   Apart from the "!important" setting on individual declarations, this strategy gives author's style sheets higher weight than those of the reader. User agents must give the user the ability to turn off the influence of specific author style sheets, e.g., through a pull-down menu.

---

So the behaviour you are observing happens  **because of specificity**.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Actually it's not about specificity, as the cascade (the tie-breaking mechanism) is not used at all: see the answer I posted. Moreover, specificity should not apply as we're dealing with different origins. Finally, if it specificity did apply we could use `#all { color green; }` and insert `<body id="all">` at the beginning of the document, obtaining a specificity of (0,1,0,0), vs. (0,0,1,1) from the user agent. You can check [the link is still not green](http://jsfiddle.net/rj0d19ap/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather embarrassed... I tried deleting this question but it was too late. In case another person finds the same issue, the answer is pretty clearly explained at the beginning of the section I quoted in the standard. Namely, [the definition of specified value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specified-value):

> User agents must first assign a specified value to each property based on the following mechanisms (in order of precedence):
>
> 1. If the cascade results in a value, use it.
> 2. Otherwise, if the property is inherited and the element is not the root of the document tree, use the computed value of the parent element.
> 3. Otherwise use the property's initial value. The initial value of each property is indicated in the property's definition.

So, inheritance only applies if there is no prior definition, be it provided by the user agent, the user or the author (only then do we *get to* point 2)... Pretty clear, and again I'm embarrassed to have missed it!

I will not choose my own answer. Feel free to copy and paste!